# How to remove elevation under the toolbar on all activites

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar, elevation

I'm trying to get rid of the elevation under the toolbar by using `app:elevation="0dp"` but it only works in the main activity xml. When I go to other activities I can still see the elevation, any ideas how to completely get rid of the elevation under my toolbar?

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.khalid.myapplication3.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is what I got after including toolbar in other activities layouts

[image]

Comment: create a layout with toolbar and set elevation and include that in all layouts required

Comment: I'm using content_main as a container for my fragments. So if I do what you suggested the toolbar will be replaced with the new fragment.

Comment: Just like you do  `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` do the same for toolbar include the layout containing toolbar with elevantion set to 0    wherever required ie in place of toolbar widget and you don't have to alter anything other than that

Comment: I did as you said and I ended up with a 2nd toolbar under the first one. I think I'm confusing toolbar with something else. I haven't called the toolbar in any other activity but main activity but it could be b/c the 2nd activity is a child of the first one ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem before, and it looks like you're using a theme that doesn't extend `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`. When you're using a `Toolbar` in your XML layout, you have to hide the default `ActionBar` so they don't conflict.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, make sure you set the theme for the activity you're having a problem with:

```
<application ...>
    <activity ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: after doing that it disabled the toolbar. Do I need to include the toolbar in every xml layout ? for the back button etc.

Comment: I finally got it. I was confusing the toolbar with the actionbar thinking they are the same. I did as you said and then included my original toolbar in the layout. Then I noticed that the toolbar was overlapping with the content so I had to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" which fixed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity XML, just add **app:elevation="0dp"** attribute to AppBarLayout. This will cause no elevation to all fragments under this activity. Here, I use a frame layout for the fragment containers.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.blog.BlogActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            // my code: remove for brevity 

            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```